# wordpress feed invalid [403 forbidden]

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I have blog with cms wordpress, and this feed blog is not working..
my blog `om-gadget.com`
feed url should it `om-gadget.com/feed/`

this url always invalid when I submit to mailchimp

I check with validator*w3*org and result is 403 forbidden

I tried deactivate all plugin and use default theme, but unchanged..

what should I do?

here code feed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
>

<channel>
    <title>OM GADGET</title>
    <atom:link href="http://om-gadget.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://om-gadget.com</link>
    <description>Gadge For Live, Gadget For Fun</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 04 Aug 2016 07:29:40 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.5.3</generator>
    <item>
```

Comment: nothing to do with mailchimp. you need to figure out why your apache/WP are denying access to that url.

Comment: @MarcB but why this feed work normally with feedburner...?